# this.echo is not working in this.thenOpen

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, casperjs

I wrote a simple CapserJS script based on [CasperJS - How to open up all links in an array of links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17926532/casperjs-how-to-open-up-all-links-in-an-array-of-links)
and it does not print the title.

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var i = -1;
var links;

casper.start('http://www.waspbarcode.com/barcode-scanners', function() {
  links = ['https://www.yahoo.com'  ,
           'https://www.google.com' ,
           'http://stackoverflow.com']
});

casper.then(function() {
   this.each(links, function() { 
        i++;

        this.thenOpen(links[i], function() {
            this.echo(this.getTitle());
        });
    }); 
    this.exit();
});

casper.run();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you did a `this.exit();` just after trying to open the urls in `links`.

You need to understand that this works asynchronously. The programs exits immediately after casperjs starts loading the links one after the other.