# CasperJS open links in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, casperjs

I'm using CasperJS to scrape a table to collect the name, address, city and URL.  I've been able to collect the information and put it into an array but am having problems opening the URL. I want to open the URL for addresses that have a match (I parse the address to match a street name and push the URLs into an array mLink).  I've set mLink as a global variable but not sure if I need to pass it in an argument.  Also, I've tested getUnclaimedAmount and that function appears to be working correctly.

I've tried looking at the following link, but am still having issues:
[CasperJS - How to open up all links in an array of links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17926532/casperjs-how-to-open-up-all-links-in-an-array-of-links)

```
casper.then(function() {
    // Call functions and get name, address, city, URL into individual arrays
    names = this.evaluate(getName);
    addresses = this.evaluate(getAddress);
    cities = this.evaluate(getCity);
    links = this.evaluate(getLink);

    // Merge name, address, city, URL arrays into 'info' array.
    for(var i = 0, l = names.length; i < l; i++) {
        info[i] = {};
        info[i].Name = names[i];
        info[i].Address = addresses[i];
        info[i].City = cities[i];
        info[i].URLs = links[i];

        //Parse the address to find the street that matches user's input
        var parsed_address = info[i].Address.split(" ")

        //Matching street name will return the URL and append an array of URLs
        for(var ii = 0, plen = parsed_address.length; ii < plen; ii++){
            lowercase_name = parsed_address[ii].toLowerCase()
            if (lowercase_name == street){
                  mAddress.push(info[i].Address)
                  mLink.push(info[i].URLs)
            };
        };
    };

});

Casper.then(function() {
    //Open the URL for a matching address
    for(var i = 0, len = mLink.length; i < len; i++){
        casper.thenOpen(mLink[i]);

        //Get the unclaimed amount
        amount = this.evaluate(getUnclaimedAmount);
        this.echo('Unclaimed Amount: ' + amount);
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
casper.thenOpen(mLink[i]);

casper.then(function() {
        //Get the unclaimed amount
        amount = this.evaluate(getUnclaimedAmount);
        this.echo('Unclaimed Amount: ' + amount);
});
```

as when you open a link you also need to wait!