# casperjs evaluate function returns invalid value

Tags: casperjs

I'm now using casperjs for web crawling. Almost everything is good, but I faced some trouble. First, my code is like below.

```
casper.start().each(SOME_URLS, function(self, URL) {
    self.thenOpen(URL, function() {

        self.then(function() {
            var getDatas = function() {
                var title = $('SOME_SELECTOR').map(function() {
                    return $(this).text();
                 }).get();

                return {
                    title: title
                };
            }

            data = self.evaluate(getDatas);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        });

    });
}).run();
```

I want to get some data from webpage to 'data' variable. Sometimes data is perfectly good(on console.log), but sometimes, data is empty!

Why this happening? What did I wrong?

Comment: It looks like you're using jQuery, if you don't add it to your casper user agent there's no guarantee that whatever website you're scraping loads it. Could that be the problem? It could also be that your assignment to data is being run in the wrong order, try putting it in a separate casper.then(). Also, please provide links to website that it works and doesn't work on to help people find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you cant call `casper.start` more than once. Your loop needs to inside the `casper.start` function or inside a `casper.then`

See this [excellent SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17935210/15410) to help you do this.

Basically only call `casper.start` once and place your loop inside a `casper.then`